# Bootstrap-sass gem, "Could not find generator"

Tags: bootstrap-sass

After adding 'bootstrap-sass' when I am trying to install it i.e by rails g bootstrap:install, I am getting following message.
"Could not find generator bootstrap:install"

Am I missing anything?
Thanks

My Gemfile below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
 end
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "database_cleaner", :group => :test
gem "email_spec", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", :group => :test, :require => false
gem "launchy", :group => :test
gem "capybara", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "devise"
gem "quiet_assets", :group => :development
gem "figaro", ">= 0.5.3"
gem "better_errors", :group => :development
gem "binding_of_caller", :group => :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no generators included with bootstrap-sass, which is why you're getting an error.

It uses the asset pipeline to make the Bootstrap assets available, so they don't have to be installed into your application. You will need to `@import "bootstrap";` at the top of your application SCSS file.

Comment: @SubratRout No problem. If it fixed the issue please consider accepting the answer as correct by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: I want to add one more thing that you can setup bootstrap-sass using rails_layout which is very feasible. Checkout following links:
http://railsapps.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-rails.html
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_layout

Comment: And you can also use: https://github.com/decioferreira/bootstrap-generators for genratore.